# How To Ingerate ElasticSearch with play frame work

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, playframework, typesafe-activator

I Installed elastic Search - 1.7.2 how to I Integrate with play frame work ? Now my localhost:9200 throw this result

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Agent",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.2",
    "build_hash" : "e43676b1385b8125d647f593f7202acbd816e8ec",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-09-14T09:49:53Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Hereafter what can I do for ***integrate play***

***Version***

Play 2.4,

java - 8,

Windows - 8

Comment: What have you done so far and where are you stuck ?

Comment: You might want to [check this out](https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch), it's a bit outdated, but that might get you started.

Comment: How to use **(elastic search)** for _My sample_ project @tuxdna

Comment: ElasticSearch provides Rest API, which you can use using  Play Scala WS API - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS . That should get you started with using ElasticSearch API right away with minimum dependencies.

Comment: OK sir i will check that thanks - @tuxdna